# OpenGraphObject with Location

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I want to add a location to my OpenGraphObject (it inherites from place).
currently I have this:

```
OpenGraphObject store = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("testshoppingguide:store");
store.setTitle(this.store.getName());
store.setDescription(this.store.getName());
store.setProperty("location", )
```

but what should I add after location? I only found [GraphLocation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/GraphLocation), but I am unsure how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to pass in a GraphObject with the "id" property being the id of the location.

Try something like this:

```
GraphLocation location = GraphObject.Factory.create(GraphLocation.class);
location.setLatitude(...);
location.setLongitude(...);
store.setProperty("location", location);
```